# Get text from html tag using single class name, the html tag will contain multiple class

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I have a html line where there are tags inside tags, a single tag my contain multiple class. I need to extract the text with single class name(i know only one class name)

```
<p class="Body1"><span class="style3"></span><span class="style1">W</span><span class="Allsmall style5">extract this text </span><span class="style5">unwanted text </span></p>
```

I know the class name Allsmall alone i want to extract the text "extract this text" from the html line using Jsoup in java.

Comment: Ask the question with little more info like HTML, CSS or Jsfiddle would be better to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selector syntax to retrieve a specific element based on its *CSS* class attribute:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(
  new File("input.html"), 
  "UTF-8", 
  "http://sample.com/");

Element allSmallSpan = doc.select("span.Allsmall").first(); // Retrive the first <span> element which belongs to "Allsmall" class
```

Comment: Have you updated the snippet to use your own html source?
Saying a `NullPointerException` won't be with much help, please point to which line exactly?

Comment: ya i changed to my own code the NullPointerException comes for the line                                                             `Element allSmallSpan = doc.select("span.Allsmall").first();`

Comment: So there is some problem in your `Document` initialization. I can merely have it working locally with a sample html file having content the <p> you provided.
Could you show me how are initializing your `Document` so far?

Comment: `(html = inputStream.readLine()) != null)                                                                          Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);Element allSmallSpan = doc.select("span.Allsmall").first();System.out.println(text.text());`

Comment: The `NullPointerException` is not coming from the line you mentionned but from the line where you are reading the span content: `text.text()` (Still can not find where this variable is initialized), and this is because you are loading the html file line by line thus the first line will have no `span.Allsmall` element and consequently you will have a null reference.
You should parse the whole file and not a line by line.
Shall I update my answer?

Comment: i want to check line by line only is there any other way to do this other than parsing the  whole file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57079/discussion-between-tmarwen-and-praveenrsmart).

Comment: how to detect if the same line has two span tags with the same class name?

Comment: Then you have to remove the `.first()` call, and use simply `Elements allSmallSpans = doc.select("span.Allsmall");` which will return a `List` you can iterate over.

Comment: iterate with for or while? can u tell me the syntax?